# Open Email on Client Side and Populate it with HTML Content

Tags: c#, html, angular

I want to open the email on my client side and populate the body with the html content I have. 
I am aware about mailto: option but that doesn't support a proper HTML Body. 
My front end is in Angular 8 and back end is on C#.

Comment: You have a server-side, consider sending emails from your server site via SMTP.

Comment: I need to open the outlook on client side before sending the email.